# State whether the functions are injective, surjective, or bijective.

Tags: functions, polynomials

In the book titled: Discrete Mathematical Structures, by Tremblay; it is stated as Q.#1 in Ex. 2-4.3:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of real numbers. Find $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$, where $f(x)= x^2 -2$ and $g(x) = x+4$. State whether these functions are injective, surjective, or bijective.

$f\circ g = x^2 +8x +14$, 
$g\circ f=x^2 +2$

By my [earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2927768/424260), have gathered that as an even order function will not be having a unique x-value for each y-value so none is injective.
But, am  still not sure about disproving surjectivity. My approach is not based on calculus (that am still unable to understand, as stated on mse [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/549909/424260)); but is based on disproof by taking cases where failure occurs.

The minimum value taken up by $f\circ g = x^2 +8x +14$ is $14$.
Similarly, the minimum value taken up by $g\circ f = x^2 +2$ is $2$.
Hence, the entire range is not mapped.

Have a further request to make me understand by the calculus approach.

---

*Update* In face of comment by @Arthur, the correct minimum value for $f\circ g = x^2 +8x +14$ is given for $x=-4$, i.e. $-2$.
This is found by simply differentiating wrt $x$ & equating to $0$ to find the minima point.

Comment: You're almost right. But your minimal value of $f\circ g$ is incorrect (for instance, what is $f\circ g(-1)$?) It's also, in my opinion, better to show directly that some specific value cannot be reached, like $-100$, since you have to prove somehow that a minimum exists anyway.

Comment: @Arthur Please vet the *Update* showing the correct minimum value of $-2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a continous function $h$ on $\mathbb{R}$, satisfying $\lim_{x \to \infty} h(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty}h(x) = \infty$.

then there exists an $M>0$, such that $|x| > M$, we have $f(x) > 1$.

Also, on $[-M, M]$ which is a compact set, the continous function attains a minimum value $m$.

Hence, it is impossible to attain $\min\{m,1\}-1$, hence it can't be surjective.

If a function has attains a global optimum, it can't be surjective as we can't have values that perform better than the global optimum.

Update:

For example, given any quadratic equation with leading positive coefficient, then it satisfies the condition. I know such $M$exists, but we are not interested in its exact value, I just know it exists. For the example of $f(x)=x^2-2$, I can pick $M$ to be $2$.

Then if you look at any values $x \in (-\infty, -2) \cup (2, \infty)$, we know that $f(x) > 1$.

Now, let's look at $[-2,2]$, we found a minimal value, which is $(0,-2)$.

We can't attain value like $-3$ because we know that on the interval $[-2,2]$, the minimal value is $-2$ and outside $[-2,2]$, their values are bigger than $1$.

Comment: Please elaborate, if possible by some example.

Comment: See the update if it helps.

Comment: Was trying a visual way to better understand, say in desmos; but unable to have an idea how to plot for a generic value $M$, and generic function $ax^2+bx+c$ with parameters $a,b,c, M, x$ provided in a given range suitable for plotting. Please help by giving some inputs.

Comment: Please  help with the earlier comment.

Comment: maybe tonight. occupied now.

Comment: Thanks a ton in anticipation.

Comment: $a>0$, if $ax^2+bx+c=1$ has a solution where the solutions are $x_1, x_2$, we can let $M= \max(1, x_1, x_2)$. suppose not, let $M=1$. In general, quadratic equations has an optimal solution, hence, we can't do better than the optimal solution hence it can't be surjective.

Comment: I hope that desmos based graphical version is possibly going to be there, as stated by you earlier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83619/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-jiten).

Comment: Sorry, was elsewhere for the last half an hour. I never expected this. Anyway, had to go at that time. I will be waiting for you here for some hours. Hope, you come to the chat-room again.

Answer (score 2):

So, you have sucessfully found $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$. That's good. Now we want to study these two functions, and see whether they are surjective.

That $f\circ g$ is surjective means that for any real number $r$, we can solve $f\circ g(x) = r$. Specifically, if it is surjective, then we should be able to solve $f\circ g(x) = -10$. So we try that:
$$
x^2 + 8x + 14 = -10\\
x^2 + 8x + 24 = 0
$$
At this point we have a standard quadratic equation. If you try solving it, you will see that it cannot be done; the equation has no (real) solutions. So we cannot solve $f\circ g(x) = -10$. This means that we cannot solve $f\circ g(x) = r$ for all real numbers $r$ (as we have just found a counterexample). This again means that $f\circ g$ is not surjective.

You can show that $g\circ f$ is not surjective in exactly the same way. In general, when trying to show that a function is not surjective, this is a popular strategy. However, using the specific number $-10$ clearly doesn't always work. You will have to analyse each function and find a suitable $r$ to use in each case.

Comment: A generic approach can be to assume any value in the range represented by $r$. So, $x^2 +8x +(14-r)=0\implies x= \frac{-8\pm \sqrt{10+4r}}{2}$. It can be seen that for $x$ to be a non-complex (hence, real) value need $\sqrt{10+4r}$ to be non-negative; & hence $r \ge 2.5$. Hence, all values of $r$ are not mapped to by domain (i.e. $x$). This in turn applies to all even order polynomial functions.

Comment: In earlier comment, the last line can be implemented by converting the highest degree term to $2$, say the highest degree term is $x^{10}$, then $t^2 = x^{10}$.

Answer (score 1):

We can refer to the general fact that

- $f\circ g:A\to B$ is surjective $\implies f:A\to B$ is surjective

and in that case since $f$ is not surjective then $f\circ g$ can’t be surjective.

We can also note that $g\circ f$ is continuous and

$$ \lim_{x\to \pm \infty} g\circ f=+\infty$$

therefore $g\circ f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded from below and it can't be surjective.

As an alternative to the frst method, a similar argument can be used to show that $f\circ g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is not surjective.

Comment: @Arthur Opsss I read wrongly that! Thanks I fix

Comment: @gimusi Sorry, but am unable to gather and request elaboration as for a newbie.

Comment: In the equation, perhaps you should write the limit as $+\infty$, and then add the precision that $g\circ f$ is bounded *from below*. Right now it's a bit confusing.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thanks for the suggetion, I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

**composite function:**
\begin{align*}
(f \circ g)(x) & = f(g(x))\\
               & = f(x + 4)\\
               & = (x + 4)^2 - 2\\
               & = x^2 + 8x + 16 -2\\
               & = x^2 + 8x + 14
\end{align*}

For the purposes of determining whether the function is injective or surjective, it is helpful to consider the vertex form
$$(f \circ g)(x)  = (x + 4)^2 - 2$$
By setting the term inside the parentheses equal to zero, we find that the vertex of the parabola is $(-4, - 2)$.

**injective:**  Is $f \circ g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f \circ g)(x) = (x + 4)^2 - 2$ injective?

If $f \circ g$ is injective, then $(g \circ f)(x_1) = (g \circ f)(x_2) \implies x_1 = x_2$.  However, we can use symmetry to prove that is not the case here.
$$(f \circ g)(-3) = (-3 + 4)^2 - 2 = 1^2 - 2 = 1 - 2 = (-1)^2 - 2 = (-5 + 4)^2 - 2 = (f \circ g)(-5)$$

Since $(f \circ g)(-3) = (f \circ g)(-5)$, $f \circ g$ is not injective.

**surjective:** Is $f \circ g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $(f \circ g)(x) = (x + 4)^2 - 2$ surjective?

For a function to be surjective, its range must equal its codmain, which in this case is $\mathbb{R}$.

Since $(f \circ g)(x) = (x + 4)^2 - 2 \geq -2$, the range of $f \circ g$ is $\text{Ran}_{f \circ g}(x) = [-2, \infty)$.  If $f \circ g$ were surjective, then it range would be $\mathbb{R}$.  Since $-3$ is not in its range, $f \circ g$ is not surjective.

**bijective:** Is $f \circ g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $(f \circ g)(x) = (x + 4)^2 - 2$ bijective?

Since a function must be both injective and surjective to be bijective, $f \circ g$ is not bijective.

**composite function:**
\begin{align*}
(g \circ f)(x) & = g(f(x))\\
               & = g(x^2 - 2)\\
               & = x^2 - 2 + 4\\
               & = x^2 + 2
\end{align*}

Notice that $(g \circ f)(x) = x^2 + 2$ is in vertex form and has vertex $(0, 2)$.

**injective:** Is $g \circ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$  defined by $(g \circ f)(x) = x^2 + 2$ injective?

$(g \circ f)(-1) = (-1)^2 + 2 = 1 + 2 = 1^2 + 2 = (g \circ f)(1)$, so $g \circ f$ is not injective.

**surjective:** Is $g \circ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $(g \circ f)(x) = x^2 + 2$ surjective?

Since $(g \circ f)(x) = x^2 + 2 \geq 2$, the range of $g \circ f$ is $\text{Ran}_f = [2, \infty)$.  Since $0$ is not in its range, the function $g \circ f$ is not surjective.

**bijective:** Is $g \circ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $(g \circ f)(x) = x^2 + 2$ bijective?

Since $g \circ f$ is neither injective nor surjective, it is not bijective.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. It is like making own notes.