# How to find range of $f(x) = \frac{x^7 + x^5 + x^3 - x^2 - 1}{6}$

Tags: functions

$f(x) = \dfrac{x^7 + x^5 + x^3 - x^2 - 1}{6}$

I'm not getting any idea how to find the range of this function. I know that to find the range of a function, we find the range of inverse function. But in the case of this function, that's quite not possible maybe. By seeing the graph one can conclude that range is $(-\infty, \infty)$ But how can we find range without looking at the graph?

I try the following method.

$f(x) = \dfrac{x^5(x^2 + 1) + x^3 -1(x^2+1)}{6}$

$f(x) = \dfrac{(x^5-1)(x^2 + 1) + x^3}{6}$

Can we conclude any result from here?

Is there any other more fundamental method to solve such types of questions?

Comment: It's a polynomial (with positive leading coefficient) of odd degree. For such polynomials, one shows that $\lim_{x \to \infty} p(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty} p(x) = -\infty$. Then, using the definition of this limit existing, and using the intermediate value theorem, one can show that the range of $p$ is in fact $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Can we conclude if $\lim_{x\to\infty} p(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x\to -\infty} p(x) = -\infty$ then $p(x) = (-\infty, \infty)$? How?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate so I'll search for one, but for now : Suppose you want to show that some $r$ belongs in the range of $p$. Using the two limits and appropriately chosen values to fit into the limit definition, you can find $x_1<x_2$ such that $f(x_1) < r < f(x_2)$. Then, IVT applies and for some $c \in [x_1,x_2]$ we must have $f(c) =r$.

Comment: You also need the premise that in general, polynomials are *continuous* *functions*.

Comment: You can read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549909/polynomial-functions-of-odd-degree-are-surjective). If it answers your question, then I will vote to close as a duplicate : but if it doesn't , then let me know why and I'll search for a different post.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I didn't understand. I think firstly I should know about the Intermediate value theorem before solving this question. Right?

Comment: @Utkarsh You should know the IVT before doing this, ideally. I don't think there is a way of doing this without it.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Can we find the minimum and maximum value of this function using the concept of differentiation? Since polynomial functions are continuous functions, the range of the function will be $[Min, Max]$. Possible?

Comment: @Utkarsh No , you can only use differentiation to locate local minima and maxima : not boundary (or near-infinity in this case) behaviour. By the way, your last sentence is a consequence of the IVT : The fact that the range of the function is $[Min,Max]$ is the statement of the IVT. To solve the question here, you cannot differentiate, because the key minimum/maximum of the range is essentially presenting itself at large (magnitude) values, so differentiation is not going to be useful.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Oh thanks, Now I got it! :)

Comment: Great, that's good to know!

Comment: @Yooo Just to commiserate with your latest meta post by showing you my [recent comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21383/project-euler-again#comment162441_21383). [I will disappear this comment later; please do not cite or quote it.] According to the site rules, I cannot reveal whether the culprit is the same entity as said "toxic user".

Answer (score 1):

Consider any $r \in \mathbb{R}$, then you can show that there exists and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = r$. Indeed,
$$f(x) = r \Rightarrow f(x)-r = 0$$
but this still is a polynomial of degree $7$. It can be factored over the real numbers into factors of the first and/or second degree. Note that not all factors can be of the second degree (since $f(x)-r$ has degree $7$), so there is at least one factor of degree $1$:
$$f(x) - r = (x-a)\cdot q(x)$$
and hence $f(a) = r$.

This shows that the range of $f$ equals $\mathbb{R}$, since $r$ was chosen arbitrarily.

**Note:** The same argument shows that any polynomial of odd degree has at least one real zero.